# Can I extract function return value?

Tags: php, function, variables, extract

I noticed that in PHP `extract(some_function());` will work just like:

```
$stuff = some_function();
extract($stuff);
```

But in the PHP's documentation the extract function argument has the `&` thingy in front, and from what I know that means you have to pass a variable to it.

Comment: +1 for & thingy... But what the heck is your question exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the documentation was right, this would produce a strict standards message:

> PHP Strict standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference

So I think you just found a bug in the documentation. Congratulations.

**EDIT**

It still doesn't complain if you use it with `EXTR_REFS` as a second argument:

```
~❯ php -a
Interactive shell

php > function a(){return array('pwet'=> 42);}
php > extract(a(), EXTR_REFS);
php > echo $pwet;
42
```

Which is strange because referencing variables defined inside a function doesn't make much sense to me. I think the & might have been introduced because of this option, but appears only in the doc and is not enforced in the code.

**EDIT**

It seems I'm right, I found this comment in `ext/standard/array.c` (branches 5.3 and 5.4):

```
/* var_array is passed by ref for the needs of EXTR_REFS (needs to
 * work on the original array to create refs to its members)
 * simulate pass_by_value if EXTR_REFS is not used */
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand passes a variable by reference so that when it is used in a function, you are manipulating the original object -- not a new variable with the same value.  The documentation is telling you that if you pass a variable to the extract function, then the original object can be updated in some fashion by that function.

So, the answer is yes, you need to pass a variable to that function.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how it's changed, though, since the documentation for `extract()` makes no mention of it and it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: It might not be changed...that depends on the function being called.  However, passing a variable by reference should require that the variable exists in scope before it is passed to another function rather than being a return value as many bad things can happen such as garbage collection of the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `$var_array` parameter of the `extract` function is passed by reference (most likely) is from a holdover from older versions of PHP. Newer versions automatically pass arrays by reference.

The `extract` function creates a variable list from the contents of a (potentially large) array and it is not recommended that data of that type be passed by value.

Long story short, assign your array to a variable and pass it in that way.

Comment: What? New PHP versions automatically pass arrays by reference?